# how to create custom annotations with logics inside in Java

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create an annotation which searches for the method name starting with a word given in the annotation and execute this method.

I am new to annotations and I know that there are some built-in annotations like:

```
@override, @suppressWarnigs, @documented, @Retention, @deprecated, @target
```

Are there any more annotations?

Comment: Annotations don't execute code. Annotations can be used by code to do things. You need to read more about annotations before coming to the conclusion that they'll solve whatever is the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 11):

I am sure there are good guides there but here is a fast one, forgive me for any typos :).

You can create your own annotation easily:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExecuteMethod {
 String methodToExecute();
}
```

You can annotate your method with it.

```
@ExecuteMethod(methodToExecute = "MethodToExecute")
...
```

The code linked to the annotation looks like this:

```
public class MethodExecutor{
 private Method method;

 public MethodExecutor(Method method){
   this.method = method;
 }

 public boolean executeMethod(){
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(ExecuteMethod.class)){
            ExecuteMethod executeMethodAnnot=method.getAnnotation(ExecuteMethod.class);
            String methodName = executeMethodAnnot.methodToExecute();
            .... your code that calls the method here
        }
 }
```

You also need a piece of code to check and execute this annotation at the point you want it done:

```
for(Method m : classToCheck.getMethods()) {
   if(m.isAnnotationPresent(ExecuteMethod.class)) {
       MethodExecturor methorExectuor = new MethodExecutor(m);
       methodExecutor.executeMethod(m)
    }
}
```

Comment: One  of the   best videos about  annotations  in java: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2GohD6r8Co&ab_channel=BASELogic